# How do I have the cli add an e2e folder for my app?

Tags: angular5, ionic4, angular-e2e

I would like to do end-to-end testing with my Angular5/ionic3 app but I notice there is no e2e folder in it.  What do I need to do to use the `cli` to generate a `e2e` folder so I can begin writing my `e2e` tests?

Comment: Can you upgrade your app to use Ionic 4? New Ionic 4 apps generated using the CLI come all ready with testing support.

Answer (score 0):

I did it manually, I added the following files to my project and was able to implement e2e testing keeping Ionic3/Angular5...

https://github.com/DocGreenRob/help/tree/master/ui-ux-partial

see

```
    e2e/
    test-config/
    package.json
```